# Custom known color names i WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, colors

What i would like to do is to define my own set of known color names that WPF will lookup just lite it do with "Red", in this case called CustomRed, that works application wide.

```
// Custom known name, this is what i would like to do.
<Border Background="CustomRed"></Border>

// System color name.
<Border Background="Red"></Border>

// Static hex value.
<Border Background="#FF0000"></Border>

// Bind to data context.
<Border Background="{Binding CustomRed}"></Border>
```

Comment: Don't make your work harder, and just define SolidColorBrudhes in resources, and then apply it by StaticResource/DynamicResource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define it as a resource. In a resource dictionary define it like this:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomRed">#FF0000</SolidColorBrush>
```

Then use it like this:

```
<Border Background="{StaticRecource CustomRed}"></Border>
```

Answer (score 1):

The XAML processor uses [TypeConverters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter?view=netframework-4.7.1) to convert string values to the actual type of the property. This is how the string 'Red' is converted to the SolidColorBrush *Brushes.Red* for the *Background* Property. While you can define your own TypeConverter, unfortunately you can only attach it to your own types because you need to add the *TypeConverterAttribute* to the type. It is not possible to associate a custom TypeConverter with a framework class like 'Brush' or 'Color'.

Using the *StaticResource* or *DynamicResource* markup extensions as @MahdiAtaollahi stated is the closest you can get.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @MahdiAtaollahi's answer, you can also use ARGB values instead of hex values:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LikeGreen">
        <SolidColorBrush.Color>
            <Color R="100" G="200" B="30" A="100"/>
        </SolidColorBrush.Color>
    </SolidColorBrush>
</Window.Resources>
```

And use it:

```
<Button Background="{StaticResource LikeGreen}"/>
```